# Webkit GTK Non English Text

Tags: unicode, webkit, gtk

I'm working on an app which involves the use of webkitgtk. It works fine except non-english characters. Example, webkitgtk widget does not render the following Russian text correctly.

> Пишу в English, значит все в порядке.
>   Спасибо!

It rather display this,

> ÐŸÐ¸ÑˆÑƒ Ð² English, Ð·Ð½Ð°Ñ‡Ð¸Ñ‚
>   Ð²ÑÐµ Ð² Ð¿Ð¾Ñ€ÑÐ´ÐºÐµ.
>   Ð¡Ð¿Ð°ÑÐ¸Ð±Ð¾!

How do I make webkitgtk display international text correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The displayed string looks like UTF-8-encoded string interpreted as ISO-8859-1-encoded string. You should correctly set encoding.

E.g., if you are loading the HTML string into WebKitWebView, you should correctly specify its encoding (via `encoding` argument to [webkit_web_view_load_string](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-load-string)).

If you are loading a web page from the internet, make sure that its encoding is correctly specified (http server sends the correct Content-Type header or web page has correct http-equiv="Content-Type" specification).

WebKit engine itself should handle multilingual texts fine.

Comment: I already fixed it yesterday by setting encoding to UTF-8. Thanks.

Comment: Does WebKit supports Big5 ? If so what should I type after encoding? I cannot seem to find the list of parameters that I can supply to 'encoding'. Please point me at a right direction, thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do character set conversion. [Glib](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-Character-Set-Conversion.html) offers a great interface to do so.

Comment: Why is the downvote  for? I thought the link provided enough information about the APIs for character set conversion.